# how can i take the names of the files that are present in a file and store it in a buffer using java

Tags: java, regex, string, file

i have the below files in the folder

- DLY-20150721-BOOST_UVERSE-ADJ.xls
- DLY-20150721-BOOST_UVERSE-ADJ-BOOST-DISCONNECT.txt
- DLY-20150721-BOOST_UVERSE-ADJ-ERR.txt
- DLY-20150721-BOOST_UVERSE-ADJ-RR20150721181623+0530.xls
- DLY-20150721-BOOST_UVERSE-ADJ-BOOST-DISCONNECT-RR20150721181623+0530.txt
- DLY-20150721-BOOST_UVERSE-ADJ-ERR-RR20150721181623+0530.txt

i'm getting the filename='DLY-20150721-BOOST_UVERSE-ADJ.xls' from a source.
so by refering the file name i want to pick the associated .txt file names like

- DLY-20150721-BOOST_UVERSE-ADJ-BOOST-DISCONNECT.txt
- DLY-20150721-BOOST_UVERSE-ADJ-ERR.txt

and store it in a buffer. but i'm not getting any idea how to do. 
i hope by using a regex i guess i can pic the files. but how to pic the whole file names and store in buffer ?

Comment: So, what's the rule? You remove the .xls extension (which results in "DLY-20150721-BOOST_UVERSE-ADJ"), and pick all the file whose name that start with that string and end with .txt? If that's the rule, then do just that. String.substring(), String.startsWith() and File.listFiles() are your friends.

Comment: some times i might have the files like
*  DLY-20150721-BOOST_UVERSE-ADJ-BOOST-DISCONNECT-RR20150721181623+0530.txt

which i dont want to pick because it is having 'RR' in the file name

Answer (score -1):

I am a beginner. I don't know how to store files in a buffer. However, to find files using 'DLY-20150721-BOOST_UVERSE-ADJ.xls', try:

```
  import java.io.File;

public class X {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("FOLDER_PATH_HERE");
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    String filename1 = "DLY-20150721-BOOST_UVERSE-ADJ.xls"; // File to search for
    String filename2 = removeExtension(filename); // filename without extension
    for(int i = 0; i<files.length; i++) {
        if( files[i].getName().matches(filename2 + ".*") 
                && getExtension(files[i]).equals(".txt")
                && (files[i].getName().indexOf("RR") == -1) ) {
            //Store file in a buffer
        }
    }
}
public static String getExtension(File file) {
    String fileName = file.getName();
    int lastDot = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
    return fileName.substring(lastDot);
}
}
public static String removeExtension(File file) {
    String fileName = file.getName();
    int lastDot = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
    return fileName.substring(0,lastDot);
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question, i want to string used in getNmae().matches("") which can pick the files i wanted not the files having 'RR' in the file names

Comment: the regex used should pick 
DLY-20150721-BOOST_UVERSE-ADJ-BOOST-DISCONNECT.txt

DLY-20150721-BOOST_UVERSE-ADJ-ERR.txt

but should not pick the below files.

DLY-20150721-BOOST_UVERSE-ADJ-BOOST-DISCONNECT-RR20150721181623+0530.txt

DLY-20150721-BOOST_UVERSE-ADJ-ERR-RR20150721181623+0530.txt

your logic is picking the above four files

Comment: I've made edits. I hope it works...

Comment: Not working but i have made some edits and now its working. But thanks for the whole idea